# Reverse stack in increasing order alternately

Tags: c++, loops, stack, reverse, non-recursive

What is the most elegant way (less code?) of reversing a stack in increasing order in an alternating manner? (non recursively)

EX.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 [3 2] 4 5 6 [10 9 8 7]
```

Comment: While recursions performance is poor it is by far the most elegant solution for reversing stacks and linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::reverse`. Will this work for you?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Comment: This is the answer, although I think this doc is better: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Both references seem about the same to me.

Comment: one is community editted on is a single authors take on it. cplusplus.com has a history of poor doc.

Comment: I'm certainly not saying EVERY page on cplusplus.com is gold, I just feel like the one they have for `std::reverse` is more than serviceable.

Comment: `std::stack` doesn't have iterator so how can you use `std::reverse`?

Comment: The OP didn't say `std::stack`. If that's what he meant, I misunderstood. I just assumed he had a container of values.

Comment: @StilesCrisis What is the most elegant way (less code?) of reversing a **stack** in increasing order in an alternating manner? (non recursively)

Comment: Sure, I get it. I typically implement a stack as a `std::vector`. If he meant `std::stack`, then he's got your answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

[`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is designed to be a LIFO (last-in first-out), and so it was not designed for you  to change the indexes of values. 
If you must change the index of the items than I would recommend using a different list.

[image]
(Does anyone know who the original creator to this image so I can give proper citation)